# It's an geometry question that I got stuck on.

Tags: geometry

All the vertices of quadrilateral $ABCD$ are at the circumference of a circle and its diagonals intersect at point $O$. If $∠CAB = 40°$ and $∠DBC = 70°$, $AB = BC$, then find $∠DCO$.

Comment: What is $∠BCA$? What is $∠CAD$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since AB=BC, $\angle{CAB} = \angle ACB=40°$. Since a chord implicit same angle on circle ,  so for chord CD $\angle DBC = \angle DAC = 70°$ . Now we found $ \angle A = \angle CAB + \angle DAC = 110°$.But since it's a circular quadrilateral so opposite angle have a 180° sum , so   $\angle c =180°-110°=70°$.

now $\angle C= \angle DCO + \angle ACB$
$$\angle DCO = \angle DCA = 70°-40° =30° $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you can use the three facts that you have to find the measure of three of the four arcs in the circle.  How large must the fourth one be?